# impossible to show laravel debugbar with laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, phpdebugbar

I have installed laravel/debugbar in my laravel 6 project, however, I don't see it displayed on my page. I have tried several things :

- set `APP_DEBUG=true` in my .env file
- run `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan vendor:publish`
- run `composer dump-autoload`
- set `enabled => true` in config/debugbar.php
- add the following in config/app.php

```
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',

'Debugbar' => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',
```

Nothing helps, I still don't see the debugbar

Does somebody have an idea ? It would help an lot :)

Comment: Sounds like you've done everything right. You should not need to register the service provider as it's done automatically since 5.5, and the facade is optional for if you want to send messages to the debug bar yourself.

Comment: If you view source on the page, do you see debugbar components (CSS and JS) getting inserted?

Comment: No I don't see any debugbar CSS or JS on the page ..

Comment: I mean in the page source, not on the page. Right click, view source.

Comment: This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now.
Do you have DEBUGBAR_ENABLED set to false in your .env?

Comment: Yes nothing in the source & DEBUGBAR_ENABLED is set to true in the .env file ..